# UITextfield Change keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am new to `iOS`,

I want to change keyboard after certain characters left in `UITextField`,

for e.g.: I have String of `@"AEBPQ1234M"`

for first 5 letters I want alphabet keyboard and then for next 4 letters I need number pad and on last letter I need again alphabet.

here is the code I have tried but it's not working when I hit backspace in the keyboard.

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
     if (theTextField.text.length < 5 || theTextField.text.length >= 9) {
    [theTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
}

if (theTextField.text.length >= 5 && theTextField.text.length < 9 ) {
    [theTextField setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
}

 [theTextField reloadInputViews];
}
```

Where I am making mistake?

Comment: In other case working ?, try to use` textfieldshouldchangecharactersinrange` Delegate

Comment: It is not ideal way to do so. You should not change keyboard . it is not good user experience .

Comment: can you please help me to get code I am new to iOS

Comment: Apple Developer please check my answer.It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
    if (panNumber.length <= 5 || panNumber.length > 9) {
        [theTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
    }
    else {
         [theTextField setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    }


 [theTextField reloadInputViews];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

where `selector` `textEditingChanged:` should listen for `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event

//add following in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textEditingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

-(void)textEditingChanged:(UITextField*) sender{
    if (sender.text.length > 5 && sender.text.length < 9 ) {
        [self.textField setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    }

    if (sender.text.length < 5 || sender.text.length == 10) {
        [self.textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
    }

    [self.textField reloadInputViews];
}
```

This will be a bad experience for a user who types very fast in phone keyboard.

Comment: @Appledeveloper is this method  `textEditingChanged`  connected to UITextView using storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. 
At first declare `UITextFieldDelegate` in your `.h` file. Also set it's delegate with self.

You can set self delegate with two types :- 
1. Storyboard 
2. Code

When set with code write `textField.delegate = self;` in `viewDidLoad` method.

Now use below code in `.m` file

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (textField.text.length < 4 || textField.text.length > 7) {

        [textField setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];

    } else {

        [textField setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    }

    [textField reloadInputViews];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer.It works perfectly.I tried it then only I post the answer here.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if(string.length == 0 && range.location == 9)
        range.location = range.location - 2;

    if(string.length == 0 && range.location == 8)
        range.location = range.location - 1;

    if(string.length == 0 && range.location > 3)
        range.location = range.location - 2;

    if(range.location <= 3){
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
        [textField reloadInputViews];
        return YES;
    }
    else if(range.location > 3 && range.location <= 7){
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        [textField reloadInputViews];
        return YES;
    }
    else if(range.location > 7){
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
        [textField reloadInputViews];
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Its working when we go forward, but when I hit backspace or i cut one character it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using multiple textFields each with their own keyboard type.

Then on your end you can append the inputted strings together to do whatever it is you need to do. This is much better user experience and also much simpler to do.